# When does open timeout starts ticking on the WCF service?

Tags: wcf, timeout

I have set a open timeout property value for my service. I want to know when does this time starts ticking. Is it only when an operation is called and it is processing it and during the idle time after an operation is returned to client. 
Does it starts ticking immediately after a channel or proxy is opened using proxy.Open()?

Following is the code - 
Client Side - 
   ProxyClient client = new ProxyClient();
   var emp = client.GetEmployee(1);
   client.Close();

At the proxy side code is - 
class ProxyClient : ClientBase<{Interface}>, {Interface}
{
 protected override IEmployee CreateChannel()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(15000);
            return base.CreateChannel();
        }
public Employee GetEmployee(int id)
        {
             var employee = Channel.GetEmployee(id);
             return employee;
        }
}

Looking at the code above, where exactly the open Timeout tick starts. 
The similar question would be answered for closeTimeout also.